Matplotlib: adjust z-order of bar chart after adding all bars
When adding a series of bars to a stacked bar chart in matplotlib.pyplot, there is only one zorder argument for the entire series, and it only accepts a single integer (not an array-like, which would be preferable). My chart has several series, and the intended z-order changes at each bar position (i.e., x-axis position), depending on which series happens to have the tallest bar at that position--otherwise that tall bar will cover the others, which totally defeats the purpose of stacked bars. Alternatively, it's possible to add the bars one-by-one, setting the z-order each time, but this introduces many other complications.
Adding a series uniformly:
plot.bar(label_list, height_list, zorder = should_not_be_the_same_for_every_bar)

Adding a series bar-by-bar:
for label, height in zip(label_list, height_list):
    plot.bar(label, height, zorder = here_it_can_be_specified_per_bar)

To avoid the messy bar-by-bar approach, is there a way to iterate over the bars that have been added to the plot, and change the z-order of each bar?

Update: solution mentioned by JohanC looks like this:
for bars in zip(*axes.containers):
    z = len(bars)
    for bar in sorted(bars, key = lambda x : x.get_height()):       
        bar.set_zorder(z)
            z -= 1


Not a duplicate because this question and its solution do not use the seaborn module, whereas the proposed duplicate is exclusively possible using seaborn.

using the bottom kwarg means that your stacked bars shouldn't overlap each other. See here for an example: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html

@tmdavison that example is adding the bars one at a time, which is specifically what I am hoping to avoid. it's possible to pass an array-like in the bottom kwarg, but it requires repositioning all the data accordingly. I'd rather sort the bars and give a z-order per bar.

@ByronHawkins  Set bar with lower value to foreground in histplot sets the z-orders in a loop, after the bars have been created.  Note that the answer doesn't use bottom= (all bars start at zero) and the z-order is assigned such that the bars per x-value are shown taller to shorter. The matplotlib tutorial example, on the oter hand, draws the bars group by group and stacks them.

@ByronHawkins If you want to give credit, why don't you upvote the answer that solved your problem?

@ByronHawkins Have you noticed the author of the "other answer"?
